# gulp src - exclude folders from being copied on task execution

Tags: gulp

I know this might sound like a pretty easy question, but I've been struggling for quite a while with no real result.

I'm trying to exclude some folders from being copied with a watch command in the gulp.
I've followed [this example](https://medium.com/@jack.yin/exclude-directory-pattern-in-gulp-with-glob-in-gulp-src-9cc981f32116) (among others) but it doesn't seem to behave like expected.

Basically, the folder structure is as following:

```
- src
| - assets
| -  -  _scripts/*
| -  -  _styles/*
| -  -  fonts/*
| -  -  images/*
| - index.html
| - favicon.ico
```

And the task I'm trying to run is as below:

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
 return gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/assets/_*/**/*'])
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'))
});
```

I'd like to copy all the files inside `src/` except for `./src/assets/_styles` and `./src/assets/_scripts`, but when the task runs, these two folders are copied as empty folders (which they shouldn't, as from the article above).

For future reference, the article above says this:

```
---> for this folder structure:

file.txt
folder
folder/file.txt
folder/_subfolder
folder/_subfolder/file.txt
folder/subfolder
folder/subfolder/file.txt
_folder
_folder/file.txt
_folder/_subfolder
_folder/_subfolder/file.txt
_folder/subfolder
_folder/subfolder/file.txt

---> when using this task:

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      'src/**/*',         //select all files
      '!src/**/_*/',      //exclude folders starting with '_'
      '!src/**/_*/**/*',  //exclude files/subfolders in folders starting with '_'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

---> the result will be:

file.txt
folder
folder/file.txt
folder/subfolder
folder/subfolder/file.txt
```

The version of gulp is the one below:

> CLI version 3.9.1
>
> Local version 3.9.1

I do I prevent them from being copied over?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.*', '!src/assets/_*/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

[Edit]:  You can also use the `nodir` option with your original glob:

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
  // return gulp.src(['src/**/*.*', '!src/assets/_*/**/*.*'])
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/assets/_*/**'], {nodir: true})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

[glob options including nodir](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options)

Answer (score 0):

You should use both this `!src/**/_*`' and this `!src/assets/_*/**/*`

Try this:

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/**/_*/', '!src/assets/_*/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'))
});
```

Hope this may help you.